# Remove Owner from Stake Pool

Tags: stake-pool

Good Morning,
I need clarity on the process to remove an owner from a stake pool.

Few epochs ago, I added my hardware wallet as a owner of my stake pool. This results in the fact that now my pool is owned by 2 owners, the hardware wallet and the first wallet.
 Now, 2 epochs are passed, and I want to remove the first wallet cause I have transferred all the pledge to the hardware wallet. From my knowledge, I only need to remove the unwanted: `--pool-owner-stake-verification-key-file stake.vkey` and then resubmit the certificate.
Is that correct? Do I need to do other things? I just wanted to be sure about that.

Thanks for your time

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yest, that is correct. You need to create a new stake pool certificate only with the hardware wallet as stake pool owner (instead of both owners) and submit the new certificate.